# Laravel Carbon - can't check date without hour from timestamp

Tags: php, laravel, date, timestamp, php-carbon

I want to sum all prices from one day using Laravel and Carbon.

I can echo date without hour like this:

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($cost->created_at)->format('d-m-Y')
```

It gives me result like: **22-11-2017**

and I need to sum all results from one day, so basically I need something like

```
{{ $costs->where('created_at)**(but without hour)**, Carbon\Carbon::parse($cost->created_at)->format('d-m-Y'))->sum('price') }}
```

I have tried with something like this:

```
{{ $costs->where(Carbon\Carbon::parse('created_at')->format('d-m-Y'), Carbon\Carbon::parse($cost->created_at)->format('d-m-Y'))->sum('price') }}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the modifiers available in Carbon so that the created_at date can be grouped.  So rather than remove the time, just set it to 00:00:00 by using the `startOfDay()` method.

```
$object->created_at->startOfDay()
```

From http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs

Comment: But the dates doesn't match now because I have different dates like: 2017-11-22 20:14:14 and  2017-11-22 00:00:00

Comment: You’ll need to use the `startOfDay()` method on all dates you need to compare

Comment: But it gives me an error when I'll do like this: {{ $costs->where(('created_at')->startOfDay(), $cost->created_at->startOfDay())->sum('price') }} ""Call to a member function startOfDay() on string"" How to use this parser on first 'created_at'?